# Datadog Metric Monitor alert threshold to custom time period?

Tags: datadog

I want to set a threshold alert for my datadog metric monitor trigger it after 12 hours.

[image]

However none of the options are 12 hours. I cant seem to add it in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can ask them to add it by opening a feature request:
https://github.com/DataDog/documentation/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 0):

You can select the custom option and select hours in the duration dropdown now
[image]